# PostgreSQL DB dump location

Tags: postgresql, backup

I want to download dumped PostgreSQL databases from an Ubuntu 16.04 server.

```
sudo su - postgres
pg_dump my_db > backup_db
```

Search for the path yields the following:

```
ps auxw |  grep postgres | grep -- -D
postgres  7311  0.0  0.0 293332  3384 ?        S    Mai04   0:39 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
```

Yet I cannot find the dumped files there. What is the location of the dumped files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$HOME` of user postgres

`pg_dump` [just echoes to stdout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html), unless you specify `-f`

> **-f file --file=file**
>
> Send output to the specified file. This parameter can be **omitted** for
>   file based output formats, **in which case the standard output** is used.
>   It must be given for the directory output format however, where it
>   specifies the target directory instead of a file. In this case the
>   directory is created by pg_dump and must not exist before.

(formatting mine)

so in your case file backup_db will be in same directory where you were running `pg_dump my_db > backup_db`

next time try specifying full path to know exact location